# How to import/use static class with namespace

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have been at this for a couple days now. Seems like the simplest thing in the world but for the life of me I cannot get this to work.

I am trying to use this class in my Controller:

https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8

The class is named Encoding.php and it has a namespace ForceUTF8.

I've tried all of the following:

```
App::uses('Encoding','Vendor'); //(copying Encoding.php directly in the Vendor dir)
App::uses('Encoding','Vendor/ForceUTF8'); //(copying Encoding.php in ForceUTF8 subdir)
App::uses('Encoding’,’Lib'); //(copying Encoding.php directly in the Lib dir)
App::uses('Encoding’,’Lib/ForceUTF8'); //(copying Encoding.php in ForceUTF8 subdir)
require_once(APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'Encoding.php'); //(use plain old php require_once to load class from Vendor dir)
```

No matter what I do I get the same error: Class 'Encoding' not found.

I find the CakePHP documentation to be very confusing on this subject. On the one hand it says *not* to use `App::uses` for non-CakePHP classes because the classes might not follow CakePHP standards. Fair enough. So instead they say to use `App::import`. But then there are tons of posts saying that `App::import` is nothing more than a wrapper for require_once.

So after not being able to get `App::uses` or `App::import` to work, I tried `require_once`. Same error. Then I found a post here on so saying even when using `require_once`, you still have to 'initialize' the class in order to CakePHP to be able to see/use it. And how is that done? `App::uses`. So I'm back where I started.

Something tells me the namespace is causing the problem. When I use `require_once` the class *is* found (I'm pretty sure) because, for example, if I change

```
require_once(APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'Encoding.php');
```

to

```
require_once(APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'blabla.php');
```

it gives me an error, file not found.

But even though `require_once` seems to find it, CakePHP still says class not found.

How can I load a namespaced vendor file?

Comment: Have you added `use \ForceUTF8\Encoding;` in your code ?

Comment: In the end I had to add the following two lines:

require_once(APP . 'Vendor' . DS  . 'ForceUTF8' . DS . 'Encoding.php');
use \ForceUTF8\Encoding;

Since the class uses a namespace, I *had* to put the Encoding.php file in  a ForceUTF8 directory, within Vendor.

Cheers for the suggestion, I didn't realize I had to have both 'require_once' *and* 'uses'. Fyi, I think I was getting the 'Cannot redeclare class' error mentioned below because I was using CakePhp's 'App::uses' I decided to not use 'App::uses' or 'App::imports' and just use require_once() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cake2.x does not support namespaces so you need write your own loader

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    foreach (App::path('Vendor') as $base) {
        $path = $base . str_replace('\\', DS, $class) . '.php';
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            include $path;
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

more info here:

> http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/08/06/namespaces-in-vendor-files-and-cake2-x/

Comment: The OP's problem is not really loading the class - it's referencing it.

Comment: Yea, I saw that post, and had added that code but it gave me an error. I was reading up on the subject and it seemed that putting that code into bootstrap.ini was only necessary if the class accessed other classes that use the namespace. Since that wasn't my case I thought it wasn't necessary. Anyway, I added it back and now I'm getting this error: Cannot redeclare class ForceUTF8\Encoding in .../html/app/Vendor/Encoding.php on line 42. Line 42 is the class declaration 'class Encoding'. Encoding.php is in /app/Vendor and in my Controller I have App::uses('Encoding','Vendor');

Answer (score 3):

In Cakephp 2.x, follow following steps

at top of class file add

> use \Dropbox as dbx;

[Dropbox is vendor directory in my case]

```
 use \Dropbox as dbx;

App::build(array('Vendor/Dropbox' => array('%s' . 'Dropbox' . DS)), App::REGISTER);
    // Autoload the classes in the 'vendors'
    spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {            
        foreach (App::path('Vendor') as $base) {               
            $path = $base . str_replace('\\', DS, $class) . '.php';
            if (file_exists($path)) {
                include $path;
                return;
            }
        }
    });
```

Now call your class method.

Answer (score 0):

Base on this article:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/08/06/namespaces-in-vendor-files-and-cake2-x/comment-page-1

I'm using the paypal sdk. And this is my code.

In bootstrap.php:

```
// Add 'vendors' as sub-package of 'Vendor' to the application
App::build(array('Vendor/vendors' => array('%s' . 'vendors' . DS)), App::REGISTER);
// Autoload the classes in the 'vendors'
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    foreach (App::path('Vendor/vendors') as $base) {
        $path = $base . str_replace('\\', DS, $class) . '.php';
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            include $path;
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

In the PaypalComponent:

```
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
```

Use those classes in function:

```
$this->apiContext = new ApiContext(
        new OAuthTokenCredential()
);
```